# Selenium FirefoxDriver - WebElement.click() is getting hanged if window is closing on click using Geckodriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver, geckodriver

**Meta :-**

- Selenium 3.3.1
- Firefox v52.0.1 (32-bit)
- Geckodriver v0.15.0 (32-bit)
- Windows 10
- Java v1.8_121 (32-bit)

I have prepared two `.html` to reproduce this issue.

- mainWindow.html

  ```
  <title>Main Window</title>
  <input type="submit" value ="Open Window" id="open" onclick="openWindow()">

  <script>
  function openWindow() 
  {
   window.open("newWindow.html", "", "width=500,height=500");
  }
  ```
- newWindow.html

  ```
  <title>New Window</title>
  <input type="submit" value="Close Window" id="close" onclick="closeWindow()">

  <script>
  function closeWindow() 
  {
   window.close();
  }
  </script>
  ```

**Selenium steps to reproduced :-**

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "geckodriverWin32-0.15.0.exe");

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("file:///mainWindow.html");
driver.manage().window().maximize();

driver.findElement(By.id("open")).click(); //This works fine

String curWindowHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
Set<String> winHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();

for(String win : winHandles) {
    if (!curWindowHandle.toString().equals(win)) {
         driver.switchTo().window(win);
    }
}

driver.findElement(By.id("close")).click(); //This click is getting hanged in infinity loop and my test case is not responded. No next line executed after this line.
```

**Question :-**
Why [`WebElement.click()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#click--) is getting hanged in that case if click event is going to close current window in `firefox` using `FirefoxDriver` while it's working fine on `chrome` using `ChromeDriver`.

**Note:-** If I'm using last line as :-

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click()", driver.findElement(By.id("close")));
```

After performing click this line is also getting hanged.

Please anyone suggest me How to solve this issue?

Comment: but where are you using newWindow.html in your selnium code?

Comment: @kushalツ it is using inside `mainWindow.html` and opens new window when click on `Open Window` button. Thanks..:)

Comment: @Saurabh Gaur did you find any solution? I have the same problem

Answer (score -1):

Add following linne at the end (after clicking "close"):

```
 driver.switchTo().window(curWindowHandle); //switching to mainWindow.htm
```

FF hangs probably because it's focus is still on window that isn't there anymore.

Comment: As I'm saying it hanged means click doesn't response anymore, then how can execute next line of code for switching window..?? your answer is not helpful for me.. thanks..:)